# What is a frameset?

Tags: computer-vision, camera, intel, realsense

I just started working with realsense depth and tracking cameras. In various code scripts, I've seen 'frameset' term (probably objects) being used. Unfortunately, I could not be sure what it meant. Is it the set of frames that was obtained by a single device, that we are receiving frames from, at the same time? What if we are running multiple devices at the same time, and still want to use framesets? Should we define different frameset objects as two devices will most probably not acquire the frames at exactly same time? I might even be wrong with my prediction of 'frameset'. I would really appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

A FrameSet holds much more info than only the depth image (for an Intel Realsense D457 for example, you have depth, color, infrared data, and others). You get a frameset per device and if you want to work with multiple framesets, you need to manually extract and manipulate them (e.g. via index or time sync).

In the SDK, rs2::frameset::frameset(frame) extends the frame class with additional frameset related attributes and functions.
Often the input to an image processing application is not simply a frame, but rather a coherent set of frames, preferably taken at the same time.